# How to call a webmethod in jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is my `web service` method.

LogGeneralIncidentForm.aspx.cs:

```
public static List<SelectUsers> GetUsers()
    {
        DataTable dtUsers = SLAFacadeBLL.GetGIMUsers(Constants.GIM_USER_ACTIONS.CANLOG);
        var items = new List<SelectUsers>();

        DataView dvUsers = dtUsers.DefaultView;
        dvUsers.RowFilter = "RESPOND = True";

        if (dvUsers.Count > 0)
        {

            DataTable dt = dvUsers.ToTable();
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectUsers { Value = row["Id"].ToString(), Text = row["Name"].ToString() });
            }

        }
        return items;
    }
```

This is my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            var items;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "LogGeneralIncidentForm.aspx/GetUsers",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {

                    items = msg.d;

                }
            });

        $('#myCheckList').checkList({
            listItems: items,
            onChange: selChange
        });

        function selChange(){
            var selection = $('#myCheckList').checkList('getSelection');

            $('#selectedItems').text(JSON.stringify(selection));
        }


    });
</script>
```

But i am not getting the users list in jquery method.My web method is working properly .How to do that?What is the problem in my code? Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Comment: you might need foreach loop

Comment: My webmethod is working properly..Wht z wrong in jquery??...How it ll take the items from web method?

Comment: Keep user list in a string with pipe | separator from web service and then split the list in JQuery

Comment: your JSON calling seems to be OK..might be issue in web service ..you need to manually debug the web service and check the return value.working example of JQUERY:

  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "AddCC.aspx/GetBankName",
                data: '{"aba" : ' + aba + '}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#txtAccNo').val(msg.d);
                    // alert(msg.d);
                   // alert('one time');
                }
            });

Comment: My webservice is working finely..manually i debug it nd got the all user list. My jquery is not working.Please kindly check the code.

Comment: r u want to use web service in same domain or in multiple domains?

Comment: In same domain.Problem is nt in my web service method.Problem is how to call that GetUsers() method in jquery nd this method is returning a list of users .So how ll i get this list in jquery and that is var items=.......kindly help me

Answer (score 1):

below code will work in same domain as per your requirement..

On web page

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="call_service" runat="server" Text="Call Service" OnClientClick="CallService(); return false;" />
<asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        function CallWebService() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://......myurl..../WebService.asmx",
                data: "{'name':'" + $("#txt_name").val() + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: ShowData,
                error: error

            });
        }
        function ShowData(data, status) {
            $("#lblMsg").html(data.d);
        }
        function error(request, status) {  
            alert(request.statusText);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was something missing in your question, you forgot to mention you were using the `jquery.ui.checkList.js`.

I have taken a look at the source code for this and it expects the values passed in to be named value and text:

```
_addItem: function(listItem){
            var self = this, o = self.options, el = self.element;

            var itemId = 'itm' + (o.icount++);  // generate item id
            var itm = $('<tr/>');
            var chk = $('<input/>').attr('type','checkbox').attr('id',itemId)
                    .addClass('chk')
                    .attr('data-text',listItem.text)
                    .attr('data-value',listItem.value);

            itm.append($('<td/>').append(chk));
            var label = $('<label/>').attr('for',itemId).text(listItem.text);
            itm.append($('<td/>').append(label));
            o.objTable.append(itm);

            // bind selection-change
            el.delegate('.chk','click', function(){self._selChange()});
        }
```

You need to change your `SelectUsers` class to reflect this by renaming `Id` to `value` and `Name` to `text`.

**Update**

A working jsFiddle with name and text in the json.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yv99D/

Comment: But SelectUsers ..its just a class file..just get nd set method i hv written der

Comment: Yes but the control you are rendering is expecting the properties to be text and value not id and name. You will need the script manager and enable page methods too as @ashwini-verma has stated too.

Comment: Yes hutchonoid..i have already tried it..just go through the code inpalce of var items=[]...i want a list of user name that should come from a web service method that is GetUsers(); how to do dat thngs only.

Comment: @madhu Sorry, I can't see what is wrong with it if you have tried all of the mentioned. Can you debug the JavaScript for any further info?

Answer (score 0):

There might me many reason and for finding please go through this wonderfull article. [http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

I can even suspect these may be the reason:

**Missing [WebMethod] Attribute**

```
   [WebMethod]
   public static List<SelectUsers> GetUsers()
   {
   }
```

**Enabled page methods in your ScriptManager**

```
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Comment: yes i have enabled script manger but still its nt working..:(

Comment: okay. just for testing place this function and try to call that.

  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }

even make breakpoint to make sure whether function gets call.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/461138/Checkbox-List-With-Filtering-jQuery-Widget              just download the source code..i am using dis control...den u can know the error..plz help me

Answer (score 0):

See the following working example

// Code behind method declared static

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSquare(String value)
{
    return value;
}
```

your button whose click this has to be done

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Chnageurl" onclick="ajaxcall()" />
```

script for this

```
<script type="text/jscript">

function ajaxcall(e) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetSquare",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ value: "Vinay" }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (value) {
            alert(value.d);
        },
       error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
     });
  };
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/461138/Checkbox-List-With-Filtering-jQuery-Widget    just download the source code..i am using dis control...den u can know the error..plz help me